# Calculating the difference between 2 dates and storing it in an array

Tags: c#, arrays, string, datetime, datepicker

I want to calculate the differences between two dates, one picked form dateTimePicker1 and the other one 20 February of 2014 and store it in a string to added to my array "Patient" and be able to display it in another form label.

So far I have no errors but the program doesn't display the difference between dates.
This is my code so far:

```
TimeSpan getDateDifference(DateTime date1, DateTime date2)
{
    TimeSpan ts = date1 - date2;
    int differenceInDays = ts.Days;
    string differenceAsString = differenceInDays.ToString();
    return ts;
}

public class Patient
{
    public string patientidString;
    public string firstNameString;
    public string lastNameString;
    public string dateString;
    public string differenceAsString;

    public Patient()
    {
        patientidString = "";
        firstNameString = "";
        lastNameString = "";
        dateString = "";
    }
}

//Array
Patient[] patientInfo = new Patient[10];

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TimeSpan difference = getDateDifference(new DateTime(2014, 2, 20), dateTimePicker1.Value);
    if (textBox1.Text.Length == 0 || textBox2.Text.Length == 0 || textBox3.Text.Length == 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(" Patient id, first name and last name cannot be empty");
    }
    else
       try
       {
           foreach (Patient patientinfoIndex in patientInfo)

               patientInfo[itemCountInteger].patientidString = textBox1.Text;
           patientInfo[itemCountInteger].firstNameString = textBox2.Text;
           patientInfo[itemCountInteger].lastNameString = textBox3.Text;
           patientInfo[itemCountInteger].dateString = dateTimePicker1.Text;

           string names = patientInfo[itemCountInteger].patientidString + "  " + patientInfo[itemCountInteger].firstNameString + " " + patientInfo[itemCountInteger].lastNameString;
        listBox1.Items.Add(names);
        itemCountInteger++;
        listBox1.SelectedItem = names;
    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Contacts are limited to 20. Please delete some contacts prior to adding more.");
    }
}

//Search Button search a patients name and display his surname in the label if patient is found  display his surname
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int intTest = 0;

    for (int x = 0; x < patientInfo.Length; x++)
    {
        if (textBox4.Text == patientInfo[x].patientidString)
        {
            label6.Text = (patientInfo[x].firstNameString + "  " + patientInfo[x].lastNameString);
            PatientForm patientform = new PatientForm();
            patientform.Show();
            patientform.label6.Text = (patientInfo[x].patientidString);
            patientform.label7.Text = (patientInfo[x].firstNameString);
            patientform.label8.Text =(patientInfo[x].lastNameString);
            patientform.dateTimePicker1.Text = (patientInfo[x].dateString);
            patientform.label9.Text = (patientInfo[x].differenceAsString);

            intTest = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (intTest == 0)
    {
        label6.Text = ("not found");
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome back! First off, there is a difference between storing a value in an array and displaying a value to a user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you're not putting any value into

```
patientInfo[itemCountInteger].differenceAsString;
```

This is why nothing is showing, it's an empty `string`.

Try to give it a value:

```
patientInfo[itemCountInteger].differenceAsString = difference.Days.ToString();
```

This is how it should look:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TimeSpan difference = getDateDifference(new DateTime(2014, 2, 20), dateTimePicker1.Value);
    if (textBox1.Text.Length == 0 || textBox2.Text.Length == 0 || textBox3.Text.Length == 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(" Patient id, first name and last name cannot be empty");
    }
    else
       try
       {
           foreach (Patient patientinfoIndex in patientInfo)
           {
               patientInfo[itemCountInteger].patientidString = textBox1.Text;
               patientInfo[itemCountInteger].firstNameString = textBox2.Text;
               patientInfo[itemCountInteger].lastNameString = textBox3.Text;
               patientInfo[itemCountInteger].dateString = dateTimePicker1.Text;
               patientInfo[itemCountInteger].differenceAsString= difference.Days.ToString();

               string names = patientInfo[itemCountInteger].patientidString + "  " +   patientInfo[itemCountInteger].firstNameString + " " + patientInfo[itemCountInteger].lastNameString;
               listBox1.Items.Add(names);
               itemCountInteger++;
               listBox1.SelectedItem = names;
        } 
    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Contacts are limited to 20. Please delete some contacts prior to adding more.");
    }
}
```

Comment: how do i add the difference of dates to that string

Comment: Check my answer, first of all, `difference` is of type `TimeSpan`, so for example if you want to show the difference in days, say `difference.Days.ToString()`, you have to say `ToString()` here because `Days` is an int value.

Comment: sorry can you takedown the code as i will need my program to be   original

Comment: @user3439080 - all contributions to StackOverflow are Creative Commons licensed.  See the note at the footer of every page.  This means that once anyone posts any code here, it is freely available for all.  Takedown is only something done in extreme cases if someone publishes something that was already copyrighted.  And then, you have to follow the takedown notice process described in the [terms of service](http://stackexchange.com/legal).

Comment: @PaulG can u at least change the name of the variables

Comment: @PaulG can u change the name of all the variables please, for example: patientInfo[itemCountInteger].patientidString as i was the one that provided them, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try displaying this:

```
DateTime a=...
DateTime b=...
label.Text=(a - b).TotalDays.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

When calculating the difference between *dates*, human beings almost always consider them to be *whole dates*.  That means you must treat the range as being *fully inclusive*.

Consider the example `2014-01-01` to `2014-01-02`.   How many days are there?  Almost any human you ask will say *two*.   However, a `DateTime` is always a date *and a time*.  You might be specifying the time at midnight, or you might just be ignoring the time portion.  But it's still there.

Once you have a time component, then most humans will naturally make the ending part *exclusive*.

How many hours in the range `2014-01-01 00:00:00` to `2014-01-02 00:00:00`?  *Exactly 24*.

Therefore, if your user interface is only asking for dates, and you're using a `DateTime` to store them in, then **don't forget to add a day** to the difference to account for the ending date to be treated as the *end* of the day, rather than the *start* of it.

```
DateTime startDate = new DateTime(2014,1,1);
DateTime endDate = new DateTime(2014,1,2);
TimeSpan difference = endDate - startDate + TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
int days = (int) difference.TotalDays;
```

Of course, you can get a date from your UI via one of the validating parsing methods, such as `DateTime.TryParse` (if your UI is culture aware) or `DateTime.TryParseExact` (if you are going to be using the invariant culture and telling your user to enter the date in a specific format).